# XSD file for XML

Tags: xml, ssis, xsd

I'm having a difficult time with XSD to load an XML file like below into a SQL database using SSIS. A sample of the file is below, I'm trying to the Event Data (SerialNumber, Filename ....).

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

 <Event> 

 <FileVersion>8.0</FileVersion> 

 <EventType>Full Waveform</EventType> 

 <SerialNumber>MP13531</SerialNumber> 

 <Version>V 10-73 Minimate Pro 4</Version> 

 <FileName>MP13531_20150709124825.IDFW</... 

 <EventTime>12:48:25</EventTime> 

 <EventDate>2015-07-09</EventDate> 


 <Channels> 

 <Channel>Tran</Channel> 

 <Channel>Vert</Channel> 

 <Channel>Long</Channel> 

 </Channels> 

 </Event>
```

Here is my Generated XSD however in SSIS I only see the Channels element.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Event" >
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="FileVersion" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="EventType" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SerialNumber" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Version" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="FileName" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="EventTime" type="xs:time" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="EventDate" type="xs:date" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Channels">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Channel" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```